# Area integral invariant computation

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Area integral invariant is a type of signature used in image processing. Does anyone know the algorithm for the computation of AII?

i.e. I want to calculate the area enclosed by a boundary and the intersected circle...

the boundary is not a curve with a equation but from a arbitrary profile. The image below is just a schematic drawing. The real boundary can be much more complex with the enclosed area in various positions of the boundary, i.e. top, bottom, left side...

[The red area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgoIE.png). I am using MATLAB and the image is mostly binary ones.
[image: The red area]

Answer (score 0):

If you know the equation of the circle and the line then its quite easy, if you are doing this in an image.

1. Select the pixels that are inside the circle (easily done with the equation of the circle). If you need to compute the AII as a ratio, then count the pixels you have.
2. Separate the pixels above and below the line. You can do this easily if you know the equation of the line, or the value of the line in each column. Go column by column and discard the pixels that are above the value of the line. Count the result.
3. That's it! If you want the AII without a ratio, then the number of pixels in 2 is the result. If you want it as a ratio, divide the number of pixels of 2 by the number of pixels of 1.

Comment: I forgot to mention the line is not drawn based on any equation, but from the profile of boundary or so...

Comment: Also, the pixel with respect to the line cannot be separated by the column value of the line, since sometime the area can be on the top the line depending on the shape of the line.

Comment: @sytheve then even easier, isn't it? *"or the value of the line in each column"*

Comment: @sytheve ah of course, I am assuming that the domain is discrete, so with this method you dont "break" the pixels. If you want it to be more accurate, then you need to compute the intersection between the line and the pixels and get the section of the area below the line. However, thats easy to do/google so I am not adding it to my answer.

Comment: @sytheve you are welcome. Cosnider accepting any of the asnwers of it helped you

Comment: @sytheve However, I do not thing that breaking the pixel into pieces above and below the boundary is needed. AII wil not be a much better feature if you do that, as those approximation errors will "average out"

Answer (score 0):

If you only have the image and no equations, you can still select all the pixels you want by giving your algorithm one pixel in the area you want to calculate and then recusivly check all neighbors and add them to you area, if they are white. When you are done, just count the pixels you have. The result is in some sense the are of the region you wanted.

Comment: How to select the area in the first place? Now I am using "imfill" function but it is very time-consuming especially with large images...like 1000x1000

Comment: Yes you can select the area by using `xor(originalImage,imfilledImage)`. Make sure to convert your binary image to logical explicitly. I don't see any other (faster) possibility.

Comment: Also, when using `imfill` remember to specify the correct connectivity.

Comment: Thank you...guess I can only use the time-consuming one...=.=